# One frame contains another frame or part of it SpriteKit swift iOS

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, position, nodes, frames

I am developing my first game with SpriteKit and have the following problem: I need to detect if one frame contains another frame or at least a part of it. Typical function is node.contains(anotherNode.position). But I need to check not one CGPoint(position) but the whole frames. Could somebody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given 2 sprites

```
let spriteA = SKSpriteNode()
let spriteB = SKSpriteNode()
```

you can check if spriteA is inside spriteB

```
spriteA.frame.contains(spriteB.frame)
```

> Please note that this will not work with simple `SKNode(s)`, you actually need a subtype which has a frame like `SKSpriteNode`, `SKLabelNode`, ...

Comment: Few more additions to answer: `spriteA.frame.intersects(spriteB.frame)` to know if two sprites intersect each other. `let rect = spriteA.frame.intersection(spriteB.frame)` to know the amount of frame sprites are intersecting.

Comment: For `SKNode` you should use `calculateAccumulatedFrame()` first

Comment: Thank you so much! That works, if the whole frame is within another one. The Kamran's comment is very important, too.

Comment: This also will not work if A and B do not share the same parent

Comment: with `SKNode`, you can calculate the frame using `calculateAccumulatedFrame`